# Cocos 2D Chipmunk - Collision ignored when collision is animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

recently my sidescroller game started to present a strange behaviour when it comes to collisions.

In topics to make it clearer:

- I have my Hero, that is a CCNode, having a physics body. She also has a CCSpriteNode to represent its shape and another CCNode to treat the collisions between she and the ground.
- I have an Enemy that has a similar structure, besides another node to represent its melee weapon. When the enemy attacks, its weapon is animated by a keyframe sequence and a physic body is added to it. The codes for both physics bodies are:

Hero.m

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB{
self.physicsBody.collisionType = @"sophy";
self.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[@"sophy"];
self.physicsBody.collisionMask = @[@"ground",@"rockWall",@"pit", @"orb",@"enemyAttack"];
self.summoningPillar = NO;

self.footNode = [self getChildByName:@"footsensor" recursively:NO];
self.footPosition = self.footNode.position;
self.foot = self.footNode.physicsBody;
self.foot.sensor = YES;
self.foot.collisionType = @"foot";
self.foot.collisionCategories = @[@"foot"];
self.foot.collisionMask = @[@"ground"];

CCPhysicsJoint* ankle = [CCPhysicsJoint connectedPivotJointWithBodyA:self.physicsBody bodyB:self.foot anchorA:self.footNode.position];
ankle.collideBodies = NO;
self.animationManager.delegate = self;

}
```

Enemy.m

```
-(void)setAttacking:(BOOL)attacking{
if (self.attacking == YES && attacking==YES) return;
_attacking = attacking;
if (attacking){
    self.attackNode.name = @"sickle";
    self.attackNode.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:30 andCenter:ccp(-10,0)];
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.sensor = YES;


    self.attackNode.physicsBody.collisionCategories = nil;
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.collisionType = @"enemyAttack";
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.collisionCategories = @[@"enemyAttack"];
    self.attackNode.physicsBody.collisionMask = @[@"sophy"];
}
else{
    self.attackNode.physicsBody = nil;
}

}
```

**THE PROBLEM IS**

This collision just happens when both bodies are moving, if the hero is stopped, and the weapon comes towards it, the collision is just ignored, and the delegate method to treat it is not called, obviously.

Sometimes it happens more than once, after the first collision, it can be seen in the following video:

http://youtu.be/r1WTRjj_gQU

**SOLVED**

The physics body that is animated must be kinematic type to have its collision treated even when both velocities are 0.

```
self.attackNode.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic;
```

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer rather than editing the question

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.

The physics body that is animated must be kinematic type to have its collision treated even when both velocities are 0.

```
self.attackNode.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic;
```